# How to set source of image as user control using C# Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I want to set the source of image which is user control using C#, how can I do that?
Here is my user control.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App4.MyImage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">


    <Image x:Name="MyImageControl" Width="100" Height="100"  
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           ManipulationDelta="MyImage_ManipulationDelta" 
           ManipulationMode="TranslateY,TranslateX,Rotate"
           Tapped="MyImage_Tapped" RightTapped="MyImage_RightTapped">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

</UserControl>
```

I tried this but does not work

```
string url = "ms-appx:///Assets/21.png";
MyImage image = new MyImage();
image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));
```

Comment: it should be MyImageControl.Setvalue()

Comment: no its not it should be MyImage as the name of control I checked that .